# Why do parentheses in an IN clause affect the result of a SELECT query?

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to execute a `SELECT` query which contains an `IN` clause with the C# CQL driver on Cassandra 2.0.

I have a simple table that looks like

```
CREATE TABLE test.in_clause (key_val text PRIMARY KEY);
```

with a single value

```
INSERT INTO test.in_clause (key_val) VALUES ("some value");
```

I can then use a `PreparedStatement` to execute my query.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("localhost").WithPort(9048).Build();
ISession session = cluster.Connect("test");
var ps = session.Prepare("SELECT * FROM in_clause WHERE key_val IN ?");
var list = new List<string>() { "some value", "something", "else" };
var bs = ps.Bind(list);
var rs = session.Execute(bs);
foreach (var row in rs.GetRows()) {
    Console.WriteLine(row.GetValue<string>("key_val"));
}
```

and this prints the single row in the table.

**However**, if I add parentheses `()` around the bind placeholder `?`, no results are found. That is, if I use

```
var ps = session.Prepare("SELECT * FROM in_clause WHERE key_val IN (?)");
//                                                      these guys: ^ ^
```

the `RowSet` returned by `ISession.Execute` contains no rows. Why does this happen?

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the red parentheses in the [CQL documentation for `SELECT`](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) which might explain this behavior. It might have something to do with term tuples, but those are only present in Cassandra 2.1.

Comment: Looking over the linked documentation, in the section "Using the IN filter condition", wouldn't those parentheses be interpreted as creating a list?

Comment: @Vlad274 A collection of _terms_, yes, that's what I think also.

Comment: Binding a list already adds parenthesis. So by adding extra parenthesis, Cassandra may understand it is a list of tuples. For instance, for clustering keys, you can write `(ck1,ck2) in ((1,2),(2,3),(4,5))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the CQL syntax, when using the `IN` operator followed by parenthesis and query markers `?`, Cassandra expects a **fixed** amount of parameters.

The following query expects 2 parameters of the same type as key.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE key IN (?, ?)
```

The following query expects 1 parameter of the same type as key.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE key IN (?)
```

On the other hand, the operator IN followed by a single query marker ?, expects a parameter containing a list of values of **variable length**.

The following query expects 1 parameter, a list of values of the same type as key:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE key IN ?
```

Comment: Can you describe how you interpret the CQL syntax? I'm misunderstanding the notation.

Comment: I think it is not well documented. Here is the [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4210) for supporting variable-sized parameter list. Its a design choice, to make it easier for Cassandra to parse it and to identify that a parameter with a list is expected.